# Android : Passing button click response from getView() method of adapter class to mainActivity

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-button, onclicklistener

The question is simple. I have written a seperate class which extends ArrayAdapter. This adapter deals with couple of TEXTVIEWs and a BUTTON. The problem is I am not sure whether I have take the response from Button's onClickListener written in getView() method to the main_activity. The main_activity has lot of logic to be followed based on the button response. Could you please let me know how to get the button response to main_activity ?

Following is the getView method

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {      
    ViewHolder holder;   
    int type = getItemViewType(position); 

    if (convertView == null) { 
        holder = new ViewHolder();  
        switch (type) {
        case 0:
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.group,  null); 
            holder.menuItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
            break;              
        case 1:
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.confirmitem,  null); 
            holder.menuItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvConfirmItem); 
            holder.quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity); 
            holder.cancel   = (Button)   convertView.findViewById(R.id.bCancel); 

            //   cancel button
               holder.cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
                    public void onClick(View v) {                   
                        Log.i("ConfirmAdapter ","Button postion  "+ position + "canceled item : " + menuItemList.get(position).getTicketItemObject().getName() ); 
                        }       
                });   
            break; 
         }  
        convertView.setTag(holder); 
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }    

    switch (type) {
    case 0:         
        holder.menuItem.setText(menuItemList.get(position).getTicketItemObject().getCategoryName()) ; 
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);  
        break;              
    case 1:
        holder.menuItem.setText(menuItemList.get(position).getTicketItemObject().getName());
        holder.quantity.setText(Integer.toString(menuItemList.get(position).getTicketItemObject().getItemCount())); 
        break; 
     }

    return convertView; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about having a reference to the activity in your arrayadapter's constructor?
Something like

```
public YourArrayAdapter(YourActivity a){
     mActivity = a;
}
```

And referring mActivity from the onClickMethod?

In your YourActivity you can have an `onItemButtonClicked()` method to be called from there.