# Android : startActivityForResult and OnActivityResult in getView() method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter, android-button, start-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android : Passing button click response from getView() method of adapter class to mainActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086039/android-passing-button-click-response-from-getview-method-of-adapter-class-t)

I have written a  class which extends ArrayAdapter. This adapter deals with couple of TEXTVIEWs and a BUTTON. For every button click, I want to establish 2 way communication with the next activity through intent. Is that possible to use startActivityForResult  and OnActivityResult  in getView() method. If so , could you please let me know how to use it.

Thanks in Advance.

Following is the getView method

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {      
    ViewHolder holder;   
    int type = getItemViewType(position); 

    if (convertView == null) { 
        holder = new ViewHolder();  
        switch (type) {
        case 0:
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.group,  null); 
            holder.menuItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
            break;              
        case 1:
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.confirmitem,  null); 
            holder.menuItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvConfirmItem); 
            holder.quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity); 
            holder.cancel   = (Button)   convertView.findViewById(R.id.bCancel); 

            //   cancel button
               holder.cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
                    public void onClick(View v) {                   
                        Log.i("ConfirmAdapter ","Button postion  "+ position + "canceled item : " + menuItemList.get(position).getTicketItemObject().getName() ); 
                        }       
                });   
            break; 
         }  
        convertView.setTag(holder); 
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }    

    switch (type) {
    case 0:         
        holder.menuItem.setText(menuItemList.get(position).getTicketItemObject().getCategoryName()) ; 
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);  
        break;              
    case 1:
        holder.menuItem.setText(menuItemList.get(position).getTicketItemObject().getName());
        holder.quantity.setText(Integer.toString(menuItemList.get(position).getTicketItemObject().getItemCount())); 
        break; 
     }

    return convertView; 
    }
```

Comment: Please don't re-post questions: [Android : Passing button click response from getView() method of adapter class to mainActivity](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14086039/1267661). Try to improve your original question if you want to attract more attention to it.

Comment: it was by mistake.. thanks

Comment: What do you mean? You wanna start directly the activityforresult in getView() or in the button click whose onClick() is written in getView() method?

Comment: Actually I want to take the button click response back to mainActivity. I do not find a way to do this. hence i plan to startactivity from Onclick inside the getView(). Please let me know if this is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know:

**pseudo code(untested):**

```
holder.cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
                    public void onClick(View v) {                   
                        Log.i("ConfirmAdapter ","Button postion  "+ position + "canceled item : " + menuItemList.get(position).getTicketItemObject().getName() ); 
                        }

((Activity) passedContext).startActivityForResult(.....) ;      
                });
```

Where passedContext is the context you need to initialize in the constructor of your customadapter class like below.

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
          private Context passedContext;
          CustomAdapter(Context context)
     {
         passedContext = context;
     }
}
```

When you instantiate the CustomAdapter from your main activity, do the following:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainAcitvityClassName.this);
```

The above returns the result to the main activity, though you start this from the non-activity class. So, you might need to define the onActivityResult(...) in the MainActivity class. I guess this is what you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Appu, I have used the adapter class as inner class and achieved this. I will check this out in future.. thanks again